# Add Dynamic Multiple Boxes Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've created a custom post type in wordpress called Product, and created a custom box called "What's Included". How would I create an "Add New Included Item", to create dynamic boxes?

It would look similar to how you can add multiple custom fields, but instead of one field, it's a "What's Included" object.

Any ideas?

`'What’s Included' => array(
        array( '_wi_title', 'Title'),
        array( '_wi_thumbnail', 'Thumbnail'),
        array( '_wi_title', 'Description', 'textarea')
    ),`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)? Sounds like it would fit your needs perfectly, although it is indeed possible to create a dynamic form in a custom meta box. A non-hierarchal taxonomy would allow you to repeat items you include often, as well.